# How can I have two versions of my app on my phone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

I have an app that is currently in the App Store. I am working on an update and want both the new version and the old version to exist on my phone. Do I have to do anything special in XCode or in iTunes Connect/Provisioning Portal to ensure I can run two versions of the same app on my phone?

Comment: I wouldn't. First off, how do you remember which one is which? I'd recommend simply duplicating your project (if you want to), so that you can return very easily to a previous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'll have to make your new version use a different bundle identifier.

Comment: If you change the bundle identifier, you'll have to use either a generic provisioning profile (e.g. the Team Provisioning Profile managed by Xcode) or a new one you create. Either way this will screw up Push Notifications, GameCenter, and iCloud (and possibly In App Purchase?) to your second app, as they are dependent on the bundle id. Unfortunately it's often easier to just switch back and forth rather than keep both versions installed.

Comment: If I use a different bundle id, that means I have to keep track of 2 sets of profiles then?